# offer facebook connect when user visits wordpress blog

Tags: facebook, wordpress

Is there a way to detect if a user is logged in at facebook when he or she is visiting your wordpress blog, and then offer to connect with facebook such that he is instantly logged in at your blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way of knowing if a user is logged in to Facebook unless they've authorized your app (at which point, you have what you need) for privacy reasons. I would offer Facebook Connect to all visitors of your blog (discretely, of course) with an option to hide the Connect box/area in the future (like [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/); scroll down about a third of the page and you'll see an `fb:like-box` with a "Disable Facebook on Ars Technica" underneath). This will give your visitors a chance to connect to Facebook, but won't annoy those who never want to hear about Facebook again.

Comment: thanks- what is the best plugin to do this? we'd also like to add the possibility for recommending posts etc